# Javascript - How do I prevent functions from running multiple times, incrementally, after each button click?

Tags: javascript, html

I am flabbergasted trying to figure out a way to prevent the button click from rendering multiple times based on the number of clicks. If you I click "submitButton" once, everything runs once. If I click it a second time, everything runs twice. If I click it a third time, everything runs three times... And so on...

Here is the code I am running to initiate the running of several functions. The subsequent functions grab data from a database, creates batches of 100, then inserts that data into an HTTP POST request.

```
      submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (document.getElementById("subject").value == "") {
          alert(
            "Please add a Subject for your Push Notification before sending."
          );
        } else if (document.getElementById("body").value == "") {
          alert(
            "Please add a Message Body for your Push Notification before sending."
          );
        } else if (
          document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]:checked").length < 1
        ) {
          alert("Please select a Jump-To page before sending.");
        } else {
          btn.classList.add("button--loading");
          submitButton.disabled = true;
          SelectData();
        }
      });
```

Following `SelectData();` are the functions that batch, create and send the HTTP POST request. At the end of all of this, I've attempted to add the following to prevent some type of storage of EACH click event, operating under the assumption that is my problem. That is, that each click is being stored locally in the browser, and thus if number of clicks = 2 then `SelectData();` will run twice along with all other functions related to the click event.

```
            submitButton.removeEventListener("click", null);
            submitButton.disabled = false;
```

I was hopeful the above would be my answer, but it has not done anything differently. I'd love some help and am happy to provide more specifics if necessary, but i am stumped. I appreciate your help in pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: The fact that when you click a second time the `SelectData` function is run twice makes me think that there is some scoping issue where your `addEventListener` is actually run on button click too (adding additional identical event listeners) and not just on page load. Can you post the surrounding code?

Comment: You actually pointed me in the right direction. It was down stream code that was a bit messy that was creating the "incrementally running functions onclick" issue. It was a for loop that iterated and global variable equal to an array. The for loop built the array each time the button was clicked, which incremented that function and subsequent functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [click() firing multiple times](/q/3460562/90527)

Answer (score 0):

The second argument for `removeEventListener` must be exactly the function provided to `addEventListener`

```js
function myOnClickFunc() {
 console.log("oh jolly, a click!")
}

myElement.addEventListener("click", myOnClickFunc)
myElement.removeEventListener("click", myOnClickFunc) // note the exact same object is passed
```

This would probably fix it. Though it is preferable for you to rewrite your code in a way where you use the same event listener repeatedly instead of removing and readding it.

Comment: I found the cause of my incrementation issue elsewhere in my code. HOWEVER, for future reference rather than removeEventListener, i have found situations where the establishing "once" for the listener accomplishes the desired outcome. Example below:
`Element.addEventListener("click", function () { 
  event.preventDefault();
  //do something//
  }, {once:true}); `

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple you can create your buttons like this:

```
<button onclick="executeFunction(this)">
 Start
</button>
```

and on javascript , create the function like this :

```
function executeFunction(button){
   button.disabled = true ; //first disable button !
 
   //put your code here !
 
   button.disabled = false; //finally endisable button !
}
```

The Key is that you should
make sure **you have the first and the last instructions dedicated for the button** because it makes it more secure and produces the correct behavior no matter how fast you spam it !

### In case of sending an HTTP POST request :

you just have to do it a little bit differently :

```
<button onclick="executeFunction(this)">
 Start
</button>
```

and on javascript , create the function like this :

```
function executeFunction(button){

   button.disabled = true ; //first disable button !
   var unlockButtonAgain = function (){ // function inside this function 
      button.disabled = false; //finally disable button !
   }
   
   //SOME CODE HERE ...
   var myPromise = myApiCall();


   myPromise
   .then(unlockButtonAgain)  // if success unlock the button
   .catch(unlockButtonAgain);// if fail unlock the button also
}
```

in you function `myApiCall` you need to return the promise or save it in a variable so that you can access it and use then/catch on it

```
function myApiCall(){ | function myApiCall(){  | function myApiCall(){
  return  $.ajax({    |   return fetch("url"); |   return axios.get('url')
              //...   |                        |
          });         |                        |
}                     | }                      | }
          OR                    OR                        OR
```